# Este Diccionario requiere System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

Estoy tratando de mostrar datos de SQL en un pdf mediante MVC EF pero me sale el siguiente error al clickear para obtener los datos:

> El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'ProviEntity.V_CuetaWeb', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProviEntity.V_CuetaWeb]'.

He intentado varias opciones pero no he dado con ninguna que me funcione, agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda o consejo o comentario.

---

***Clase:***

```
public partial class V_CuetaWeb
    {
        public string Agencia { get; set; }
        public string Cobrador { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Titulo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Endoso { get; set; }
        public string Domicilio { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Piso { get; set; }
        public string Dpto { get; set; }
        public string Mono { get; set; }
        public string DniTipo { get; set; }
        public double DniNumero { get; set; }
        public string Barrio { get; set; }
        public string Localidad { get; set; }
        public string Provincia { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Celular { get; set; }
        public string acidzona { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Sorteo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Cuota { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Monto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CodigoPostal { get; set; }
        public string barras { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> deuda { get; set; }
        public string Solicitud { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Vencimiento { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> ValNom { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> PlanAntes { get; set; }
        public string DescPlanActual { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime FechaSorteo { get; set; }

        public string suscriptor { get; set; }
    }
```

***Controlador:***

```
public ActionResult Index(string buscar, string buscarCuota)
        {
            PDFPrinter db = new PDFPrinter();
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = buscar;
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = buscarCuota;

            var datos = from s in db.V_CuetaWeb
                        select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(buscar) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(buscarCuota))
            {
                datos = datos.Where(s => s.Titulo.ToString().Contains(buscar.ToUpper())
                                       || s.Cuota.ToString().Contains(buscarCuota.ToUpper()));
            }
            return View(datos.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult PrintViewToPdf()
        {
            var report = new ActionAsPdf("Index");
            return report;
        }

        public ActionResult PrintPartialViewToPdf(double id)
        {
            using (PDFPrinter db = new PDFPrinter())
            {
                V_CuetaWeb customer = db.V_CuetaWeb.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Titulo == id);
                var report = new PartialViewAsPdf("DetailCustomer", customer);
                return report;
            }
        }
```

***Index:***

```
@model IEnumerable<ProviEntity.V_CuetaWeb>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicio";
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Convert View To PDF", "PrintViewToPdf")
</p>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <p>
                    Título: @Html.TextBox("buscar", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /><br />
                    Cuota: @Html.TextBox("buscarCuota", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /><br />
                    <input type="button" value="Imprimir" onclick="window.print()" />
                </p>
            }
        </div>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Suscriptor">Suscriptor: </th>
                        <td>

                            <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</b>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                    </tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Print Details View To PDF", "PrintPartialViewToPdf", new { id = item.Titulo})
                    </td>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***DetailCustomer:*** (Aquí está el problema, ya que al acceder a esta parte sale el error)

```
@model IEnumerable<ProviEntity.V_CuetaWeb>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DetailCustomer";
}


<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Domicilio">Domicilio: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Domicilio)
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Valor Nominal: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ValNom)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Barrio">Barrio: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Barrio)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Localidad">Localidad: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Localidad)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Telefono">Teléfono: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefono)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Celular">Celular: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celular)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Descripcion">D. Plan Actual: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescPlanActual)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" abbr="Fecha">Fecha Sorteo: </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaSorteo)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Zona: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.acidzona)</th>
                        <th>Cobrador: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cobrador)</th>
                        <th>Código: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)</th>
                        <th>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Endoso)</th>
                        <th>Sorteo: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sorteo)</th>
                        <th>Cuota: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuota)</th>
                        <th>Vencimiento: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vencimiento)</th>
                        <th>Monto: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Monto)</th>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Dejo imagen (Al presionar en Print Details View To PDF): 
[image: Al presionar en Print Details View To PDF]

> ***Sucede esto***
>   [image: Luego de Presionarlo, sucede esto]

Comment: pone un break en  return View(datos.ToList()); y mostranos que contiene

Comment: No te falta sólo agregar el namespace `System.Collections.Generic`?

Comment: En la accion `PrintPartialViewToPdf` cuando obtienes los datos haces un `FirstOrDefault`, por lo tanto solo estas obteniendo un objeto y no una lista de objeto, Y en tu vista `DetailCustomer` estas esperando que el modelo sea una lista de `V_CuetaWeb`, pero desde el controlador solo envias un objeto plano de `V_CuetaWeb`.

Comment: En pocas palabra tu vista espera una lista de objeto, pero desde el controlador solo pasas un objeto como modelo.

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenido/a a SOes, 2. Visita https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 3. Edita tu pregunta agreando detalles importantes tales como el Action que tienes en `DetailCustomer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que en tu controlador mandas un objeto del tipo V_CuetaWeb

```
public ActionResult PrintPartialViewToPdf(double id)
{
    using (PDFPrinter db = new PDFPrinter())
    {
        V_CuetaWeb customer = db.V_CuetaWeb.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Titulo == id);

        // Aquí lo envías:
        var report = new PartialViewAsPdf("DetailCustomer", customer);
        return report;
    }
}
```

Pero en tu vista estás esperando un IEnumerable

```
...
@model IEnumerable<ProviEntity.V_CuetaWeb>
...
```

Si la partial view la utilizas en otros lados en tu aplicación y ahí sí envías un objeto del tipo IEnumerable, entonces haz lo siguiente en tu controlador:

```
public ActionResult PrintPartialViewToPdf(double id)
{
    using (PDFPrinter db = new PDFPrinter())
    {
        V_CuetaWeb customer = db.V_CuetaWeb.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Titulo == id);
        List<V_CuetaWeb> lista = new List<V_CuetaWeb>();
        lista.add(customer);
        var report = new PartialViewAsPdf("DetailCustomer", lista);
        return report;
    }
}
```

De esta forma, enviarás una lista de un solo elemento y tu código continuará funcionando.

En caso contrario, tendrás que modificar tu Partial View

```
...
@model ProviEntity.V_CuetaWeb
...
```

Y quitar todo lo relacionado con el foreach pues solo recibirás un objeto.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, de verdad me ha servido lo que me has dicho.